# cloning elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, replace

I am working on a form that user can add rows as he wants to. There is a link named "add row", When it clicked, I want to clone a hidden table and change it's name values, some of class names. could anyone help me about this?

```
<table class="montaj montaj-satir">
    <tr>
        <td width="62px"><input type="text" name="oper[--number--][kodu]" size="4" maxlength="4" /></td>
        <td width="38px">
            <input type="checkbox" name="oper[--number--][onay]" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="oper[--number--][terminal_hatasi]" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="oper[--number--][soket_hatasi]" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="oper[--number--][montaj_hatasi]" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="oper[--number--][yon_hatasi]" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="oper[--number--][push_hatasi]" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="oper[--number--][olcu_hatasi]" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="oper[--number--][bant_hatasi]" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="oper[--number--][vida_hatasi]" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="oper[--number--][komponent_hatasi]" value="0" />
        </td>
        <td width="62px"><span class="terminal_hatasi--number--">0</span> <a href="#" class="add hata-ekle" id="terminal_hatasi--number--">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></td>
        <td width="62px"><span class="soket_hatasi--number--">0</span> <a href="#" class="add hata-ekle" id="soket_hatasi--number--">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></td>
        <td width="62px"><span class="montaj_hatasi--number--">0</span> <a href="#" class="add hata-ekle" id="montaj_hatasi--number--">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></td>
        <td width="62px"><span class="yon_hatasi--number--">0</span> <a href="#" class="add hata-ekle" id="yon_hatasi--number--">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></td>
        <td width="62px"><span class="push_hatasi--number--">0</span> <a href="#" class="add hata-ekle" id="push_hatasi--number--">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></td>
        <td width="62px"><span class="olcu_hatasi--number--">0</span> <a href="#" class="add hata-ekle" id="olcu_hatasi--number--">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></td>
        <td width="62px"><span class="bant_hatasi--number--">0</span> <a href="#" class="add hata-ekle" id="bant_hatasi--number--">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></td>
        <td width="62px"><span class="vida_hatasi--number--">0</span> <a href="#" class="add hata-ekle" id="vida_hatasi--number--">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></td>
        <td width="62px"><span class="komponent_hatasi--number--">0</span> <a href="#" class="add hata-ekle" id="komponent_hatasi--number--">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Kablo Sıra No</td>
        <td colspan="4"><input type="text" name="oper[--number--][kablo_sira_no]" value="" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">Açıklama</td>
        <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="oper[--number--][aciklama]" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the links that have `.hata-ekle` class, increasing the value of hidden input and the span next to it.

If there is needed for a new row, user should click "add row" link and new cloned `.montaj` table should appear but `--number--` should be replaced with a unique number.

How can I do this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

I don't understand the whole process but I can give you some pointers :

1. **First method** : you write a function taking needed number in parameter and creating the table with jQuery utilities :

   ```
   function addTable(number) {
     var table = $('<table>');
     var tr = $('<tr>').appendTo(table);
     var td = $('<td>').appendTo(tr);
     var span = $('<span>').appendTo(td).addClass('terminal_hatasi'+number)
     ...
   }
   ```
2. **Second method** : you clone you table and then you search your input/span and retag it :

   ```
   function addTable(number) {
     var clone = $('table.montaj').first().clone();

     clone.find('input').each(function(item){
       var name = $(this).attr('name');
       $(this).attr('name',name.replace(/\d/,number));
     });

     ...

     $(body).append(clone);
   }
   ```

I think there is even more approach, these are the two came first to my mind. These are not necessarily the betters...